# Why does getHeaderField() return a String where as getHeaderFields() return Map<String,List<String>> in HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, android, httpclient, httpurlconnection

I am using HttpUrlConnection in my android code and I am trying to access header fields post getResponseCode() call. For a single header method is -

```
public String getHeaderField(String name)
```

where as to get all headers it is -

```
public Map<String,List<String>> getHeaderFields()
```

So whats the deal here? Are we allowed to set headers multiple times?

Documentation of getHeaderField() method says -

> If called on a connection that sets the same header multiple times with possibly different values, only the last value is returned.

So whats with getHeaderFields() method? I would appreciate if someone could give an example to help understand the difference.

Comparing with HttpResponse which has method -

```
Header[] getHeaders(String var1);
```

I would have expected method -

```
public List<String> getHeaderField(String name)
```

but that does not seem to be the case. So how do I handle this?

Comment: So you want to get the header? key and value right ?

Comment: Question is how is it possible to have multiple values for a single header. If it does (which seems to be the case in case of HttpClient as well as getHeaderFields of HttpUrlConnection) how do I get List of values for a single header in HttpUrlConnection.

Comment: Please don't tell me to iterate and get it :)

Comment: header value will be returned as string only of you have multiple values with the same header key, it will return all values as one String separated with ';' semicolon

Comment: So why the parity? It could be [`public String getHeaderField(String name)` and `public Map<String,String> getHeaderFields()`)]OR [`public List<String> getHeaderField(String name)` and `public Map<String,List<String>> getHeaderFields()`]?

Comment: I'm not sure about the last one but i suggest you to convert it to array

                       [Map <String,ArrayList<String>> myList=new 
                      ArrayList<String>
                      (Arrays.asList(getHeaderField("myHeader").split(";")))]

Comment: `getHeaderFields` returns a map, so if you already know the header name, you don't need to iterate, just do `getHeaderFields().get("headername")` to get the list of values of that header

Comment: Yep but the header may have multiple values

Comment: OP asked "how do I get List of values for a single header". That's one way to do it

Comment: He needs to pull specific header which has multiple values

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I think both approaches would work. It's just that I expected consistent APIs and not to manually do a split with semicolon. Anyways can please you add your answers to answers section.

Comment: @AniketThakur You're welcome. Answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

Headers (not sure if all of them) can have multiple values, and I don't know why the API was designed this way (`getHeaderField()` returns the values separated by `;` while `getHeaderFields()` returns a list of values, which is an inconsistent design choice in my opinion).

Well, to get a list of values for some header: `getHeaderFields()` method returns a map, so if you already know the header name, you don't need to iterate, just do `getHeaderFields().get("headername")` to get the list of values of that header.

Comment: Are you sure `getHeaderField()` gives last value only? And not all separated by `;` as @Basil has suggested?

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood the javadoc: "If called on a connection that sets the same header multiple times with possibly different values, only the last value is returned." - I thought it returns the last value, but it actually returns the last one that was **set**. I've updated the answer.